# How to update in mysql database from linux using awk/sed/linux-shell script for?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, mysql

I have a data file called 'frequency.txt' in two columns, column 1 is 'frequency' it is a number showing a repetition of corresponding column 2 which has ids .

**Example:-**

**Data**

**frequency, id**

```
 32    329
312    330
320    331
132    332
232    334
 52    336
 42    337
 82    338
 ..    ...
```

The above data has to be updated in a column in a mysql database. There are more than 100 lines and everyday I have to update it. Right now I am using this command to update it manually.

`echo ' update table.id_set set 'frequency' = 32 where`id`=329; '|mysql -B -u username -p -h database.com`

How to write a shell script which will automatically replace the value of 'frequency' and 'id' in the above echo command and run it for all the existing lines in the frequency.txt

PS:- The number of lines in the frequency.txt will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have `mysql` at hand to test with, but if it can accept multiple SQL statements:

```
awk '{print "update table.id_set set frequency = "$1" where id = "$2";"}' < input | 
  mysql -B -u username -p -h database.com
```

On the sample input, the awk command would send this to the `mysql` command:

```
update table.id_set set frequency = 32 where id = 329;
update table.id_set set frequency = 312 where id = 330;
update table.id_set set frequency = 320 where id = 331;
update table.id_set set frequency = 132 where id = 332;
update table.id_set set frequency = 232 where id = 334;
update table.id_set set frequency = 52 where id = 336;
update table.id_set set frequency = 42 where id = 337;
update table.id_set set frequency = 82 where id = 338;
```

Comment: The above idea works well, thank you. Why did you say the below 'mysqlimport' is better than your method? I am just curious if there is any technical advantage.

Comment: @CCC I think the fewer tools that you use in a toolchain, the less risk you run of breakage. If you can write the file in a way that mysql can read in natively, you remove the dependence on a shell script and awk to do more transformations. It happens rarely enough, but in this case, I appreciate andcoz pointing out that such a tool exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) or call directly [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) sql statement (via mysql).

mysqlimport doesn't like "fixed-width" data files but you can see [Loading fixed-width, space delimited .txt file into mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461790/loading-fixed-width-space-delimited-txt-file-into-mysql) for an example on how to handle them.

#### Example

This example relies on the **supposition** that the column `id` is the primary key of the table `id_set`.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/some/path/data.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE id_set
(@row)
SET frequency = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,7)),
    id = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,8,50))
;
```

Comment: This sounds like a better idea than mine; can mysqlimport do "update" operations? Maybe with the `--replace` option?

Comment: Yes, it is the goal of that option. The manual page states `If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row.`

Comment: but id's position might change, for example a new 'id'=33 might be added later on into database. So, will this be able to replace frequency for the corresponding id? id is integer in this case, but I have to do similar work for ids as characters also.

Comment: Can you show an example using above method. I tried and messed up the data but thankfully I tried it on a mock data.

Comment: The replace policy is based on table `primary key` definition. The order in the file is _irrelevant_. All depends on how you defined the primary key on the table.